# How to print first item in a string from a dictionary with a random number and print remaining numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, random

I am creating a function that opens and reads a text file, separated by commas. The function will create a dictionary of the text file and print out the first item in each string, along with a random number (1-10) as the key. The values will then be the remaining numbers in their respective string

Ex. of file

```
  January,900,483,394,883,649
  February,200,329,596,283,972
  March,120,237,923,102,787
```

I have been able to get the dictionary printed, but the output is nowhere near what I want it to be.

```
import random
def dictionaryTest():
  openfile= open('example.txt', 'r')
  monthData = openfile.readlines()
  openfile.close


  dictionary = {}
  rNum = random.randrange(1,11)

  for lines in monthData:
      info = line.split()
      key, values = info[0], info[1:]
      d[key] = info[0], rNum
      values = info[1:]

  print(dictionary)
```

Expected Output:

```
{('January, 8'): [900,483,394,883,649],('February, 1'): 
[200,329,596,283,972],('March, 4'): [120,237,923,102,787]}
```

Actual Output:

```
{'January, 900, 483, 395, 883, 649':('January, 900, 483, 395, 883, 
649'), 'February, 200,329,596,283,972':('February, 
200,329,596,283,972'), 'March, 120,237,923,102,787':('March, 
120,237,923,102,787')}
```

Comment: `info = line.split()` -.... splits at spaces - NOT commas

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like below to get the mentioned output. When you need to split by commas, you have to mention it inside the split() like below. And if you need different random numbers for each dictionary key, you have to put `rNum = random.randrange(1,11)` code line inside the FOR LOOP.

```
import random

openfile= open('example.txt', 'r')
monthData = openfile.readlines()
openfile.close

dictionary = {}

for line in monthData:
    rNum = random.randrange(1,11)
    info = line.split(',')
    key = info[0], rNum
    value = info[1:]
    for i in range(len(value)):
        value[i] = int(value[i])
    dictionary[key] = value

print(dictionary)
```

Comment: @Ravindu_Perera How would I go about removing the quotations around each number? So it would just look something like:[900,483,394...]

Comment: I updated the code to show you how to do it also. Just look at the FOR LOOP inside the FOR LOOP. There I have converted every strings into integers (type casting).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
import csv
import random

def dictTest():
    with open ("/Users/richard/Desktop/python testing/test.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
        output = csv.reader(csvfile)
        dictionary = {}
        for row in output:
            rNum = random.randrange(1,11)
            row[0] += " "+ str(rNum)
            list_ints =[]
            for element in row[1:]:
                list_ints.append(int(element))
            dictionary[row[0]] = list_ints


        print(dictionary)

dictTest()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: How would I go about removing the quotations around each number? So it would just look something like:[900,483,394...]

Comment: @Richard_K_Yu ^^

Comment: You want to typecast the data from string to int

Comment: I updated the function to show this. Let me know if you have any trouble.